# Does the shadow DOM replace ::before and ::after?

Tags: css, language-lawyer, pseudo-element, shadow-dom

[CSS Scoping](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1/#shadow-dom) says

> The descendants of a [shadow host](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1/#shadow-host) must not generate boxes in the
>   formatting tree. Instead, the contents of the [active shadow tree](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1/#active-shadow-tree)
>   generate boxes as if they were the contents of the element instead.

[CSS Pseudo-Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#generated-content) describes `::before` and `::after` as

> these pseudo-elements generate boxes as if they were immediate
>   children of their *originating element*

So which of these is true?

- First, all the contents of the shadow host (not including `::before` and `::after`) are replaced by the contents of the active shadow tree. And then, `::before` and `::after` generate boxes in the shadow host.
- First, `::before` and `::after` generate boxes in the shadow host. And then, all the contents of the shadow host (including `::before` and `::after`) are replaced by the contents of the active shadow tree.

Firefox and Chrome do the former, but does the spec describe the behavior?

```js
var root = document.querySelector('div').createShadowRoot();
root.innerHTML = "<p>Shadow content</p>";
```

```css
div::before, div::after {
  content: 'Generated content';
}
```

```html
<div>Content</div>
```

Comment: Did you take a look a the distribution algorithms of the Shadow DOM? If pseudo `::before` and `::after` elements can be considered as child nodes of the shadow host than this might describe the behavior. http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#distribution-algorithms

Comment: @DavidDomain Not much, I find that spec difficult to understand :S However, that spec seems to talk about what happens in the DOM, but `::before` and `::after` are not DOM nodes.

Comment: Likewise i am having a hard time to follow along with the spec as well. I just thought maybe the Shadow DOM is designed that way to see pseudo elements as child nodes, but that is probably not the case and would not make much sense.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

CSS Scoping spec author here.

The answer is actually, officially... undefined!

I didn't think about this interaction when I was writing the Scoping spec.  I'll send an email to the list, and we'll figure it out.  Almost certainly, we'll settle on whatever browsers currently do (which appears to be letting ::before/after work "as expected" even in shadow hosts).

Edit: The Working Group's response was unanimous - the current implementation behavior (::before/after *do* work on shadow hosts) is how it should be.  I'll edit it into the Scoping spec shortly.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key wording is in this part of [the generated content section](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#generated-content).

> **::before**
>
> Represents a styleable child pseudo-element immediately before the originating element’s actual content.
>
> **::after**
>
> Represents a styleable child pseudo-element immediately before the originating element’s actual content.

Excusing the obvious copy-paste error in the ::after description (it is a working draft), we can see that these pseudo-elements generate content outside, or "immediately before", the actual content of the element.

Compare this to this description from the [Shadow Encapsulation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1/#shadow-dom) section, it seems to confirm the behavior of Chrome and Firefox.

> The descendants of a shadow host must not generate boxes in the formatting tree. Instead, the contents of the active shadow tree generate boxes as if they were the contents of the element instead.

In short, a shadow host replaces the actual contents of the element, and ::before and ::after generate pseudo-elements immediately before/after the elements actual content. Because the pseudo-elements create boxes outside the content being replaced, the content being replaced has no effect on the pseudo-elements.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your point is that ::before and ::after are like children but are not children. However, in [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items) only in-flow children (and contiguous run of text) become flex items, but ::before and ::after become pseudo-elements. So that means they must be treated like if they were real children.

Comment: @Oriol I'm not sure I follow. If my understanding is correct, the shadow host replaces the "content", but ::before/::after create separate boxes outside that content, "immediately before" (and after). The content being replaced has no effect on the pseudo-elements, because they are outside the content being replaced.

Comment: Yes, it seems that's what happens. However, pseudo-elements are not children but must behave like they were. And the children (and descendants) are replaced. But how can we know if that doesn't include pseudo-elements (because they are not real children), or if it does (because they behave like real children)?

Comment: Does this work with ::-webkit-scrollbar ? I have been trying to add scrollbar of a ::part() but it isn't  working when styling from outside the component